# How to control z-index of a child of a sticky element

Tags: css, alignment, z-index, sticky

I have two `container` elements which have `position: sticky` and a `z-index: 1`.

One of those elements has a child node with `position: absolute`.

I would like the child node to be visually on top of both `container` elements.

This is the html structure I must keep and what I have tried:

```css
.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 10; /* this doesn't work */
}

.container {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how it currently looks:

[image]

This is how I would like it to look:

[image]

But I would like to keep the `html` structure and the `sticky` alignment of the `container` elements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sticky` element will create a stacking context thus all the elements inside cannot be placed relatively to element outside this stacking context. You have to modify the `z-index` of the first container so it's above the second one with all its child element.

```css
.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
   /*z-index: 10; this doesn't work */
}

.container {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
.container:first-child {
 z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Related question for more details: [Why can't an element with a z-index value cover its child?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54897916/8620333)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Temani Afif, I am wondering what a general solution would be for `n` `container` elements, I've asked the question here if you were interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876373/how-to-control-z-index-of-child-n-sticky-elements